# Creating a 5x5 box matrix

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to complete a task in which I have to create a 5x5 box matrix. When user click any of the box, highlight that box a number inside. Can someone guide me how to do this?

I have to use Table Layout or some thing else.

Following is the box.

[image]

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Tried TableLayout. but I think I need advise 1st. because table layout or placing buttons will take much time. so 1st get advise and then will start.

Comment: please show your codes, thanks !

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I don't have code any code yet. As I said before starting I asked for advise how to do this thing.

Answer (score -1):

[Square Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tzbv.jpg)

I created this board using onMeasure event.

So you can create custom view which extends old one and override this event for creating square view or layout.
And then you can easily add this view to TableRow inside TableLayout.
If you need I can put all needed code or if you have another question let me know.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


    int h = this.getMeasuredHeight();
    int w = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int curSquareDim = Math.min(w, h);
    // Inside a viewholder or other grid element,
    // with dynamically added content that is not in the XML,
    // height may be 0.
    // In that case, use the other dimension.
    if (curSquareDim == 0)
        curSquareDim = Math.max(w, h);

    if(curSquareDim < squareDim)
    {
        squareDim = curSquareDim;
    }

    Log.d("MyApp", "h "+h+"w "+w+"squareDim "+squareDim);


    setMeasuredDimension(squareDim, squareDim);

}
```